# DOB Query for daily refresh

Tags: sql, db2

I have a file in DB2 with Customer Name and Date of Birth. I want to run a report on a daily basis to extract where DOB is > today's date. I don't want to change the date manually everyday.

How can write the code?

CREATE TABLE QTEMP.TEST AS (SELECT NAME, DOB FROM EMOQRYCOMP.SSCUSTP WHERE ......

Comment: I guess what you _really_ want is customers whose _month_ and _day_ of birth are larger than today's month and day, regardless of the year.

Comment: DOB can never be in the future.

Comment: This is to report erroneously captured DOB's

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, DOB 
FROM EMOQRYCOMP.SSCUSTP 
WHERE DOB > CURRENT_DATE
```

`CURRENT DATE` works also, but I prefer the version with an underscore.

Comment: There wouldn't be many customers in the table who have not been born yet...

Comment: @mustaccio...there shouldn't be any ;)  But that's what the OP asked for.  Apparently he doesn't have a constraint defined.

Answer (score 0):

Following query would return all rows with dob (month and day) is greater than today (up to the end of the year)

```
select * 
 from QTEMP.TEST
where (month(dob) = month(current date) and day(dob) > day(current date)) 
   or (month(dob) > month(current date))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.test as (
SELECT NAME, DOB 
FROM EMOQRYCOMP.SSCUSTP 
WHERE DOB > CURRENT DATE
) with data with replace not logged
```

Comment: Why -1? this solution work and save solution in qtemp... [IBM Site documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html)